# How to deploy a png image to IOS device?

Tags: ios, qt

I am taking an image in QPixmap & draw that pixmap via QPainter.
  Every thing works fine on the Desktop but when I run the application on an iPad (IOS), then image is not loading there.
It is showing only Painter drawing not image?
I also have included the image in resource file.

```
QPainter painter(this);  // My code snippet
painter.setPen("#7FFF00");
QPixmap pixmap(":template2.png");
pixmap.scaled(width(),height());
painter.drawPixmap(0,0,pixmap);
```

I included the resource file in .pro file like this.

RESOURCES = \
    untitled.qrc

Please tell me where I am wrong?

Comment: Pixmap pixmap(":/template2.png"); Is it "/" missed?

Comment: No, I tried that also.
And the code is working fine in desktop but not on i-pad.

Comment: a achieved the target. thanks